# JSF button with customized dynamic image

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

*JSF-2.0, Mojarra 2.1.19, PrimeFaces 3.4.1*

I know that we can add an image to button through defining our own css class like:

```
.imageButton {
  background-image:url(#{resource['images/button.png']});
}
```

But the problem is, picture url is coming from the bean and it has different value for each user, so giving static image url is not going to work. I need sth. like that:

```
<p:button value="#{loginBean.loggeduser.name}" icon="#{loginBean.loggeduser.picurl}"/>
```

But as expected this is not working because of the icon property expects a class name. Also I've tried to define a `p:graphicImage` component inside the button but doesn't seem like a regular icon.

It should seem like this:

[image: profile picture]

Upper picture can be done with pre-defined icons with below code:

```
 <p:commandButton value="sth" icon="ui-icon-star"/>
```

But as I said, I don't want to use a static icon.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got several options. I'll list two of them below.

1. Use inline style as button's attribute:

   ```
   style='background: url(#{resource['images/button.png']}) no-repeat;'
   ```
2. Nest image inside button (note that it won't work with a command button):

   ```
   <h:button ...>
       <h:graphicImage .../>
   </h:button>
   ```

And use other CSS stylings for text output if necessary.

Comment: first solution is not working even with `background: url(#{resource['#{loginBean.loggeduser.picurl}']}) no-repeat;`. And the second one doesn't provide the behaviour of <p:commandButton value="sth" icon="ui-icon-star"/>.

Comment: If you have image url don't use `#resources` as you are not actually getting image from your resources: `style='background: url(#{loginBean.loggeduser.picurl}) no-repeat !important;'`

Comment: `style='background: url(#{loginBean.loggeduser.picurl}) no-repeat !important;'` this one works you can edit your answer with this, thank you so much.

Comment: @Ömer Faruk Almalı, i wish i know we can use backing bean variable in css directly, good luck if it works.

Comment: You definitely can access your image via resource as well. If your picurl will be of type "images/users/user123.jpg" and you will conform to EL usage rules, making your style 'background: url(#{resource[loginBean.loggeduser.picurl]}) no-repeat; !important', everything will work well.

Answer (score 1):

i just checked the primefaces 3.4 manual and i verify that `<p:commanButton>` has an attribute of `styleClass` so i guess you can use that,

```
<p:button value="#{loginBean.loggeduser.name}" styleClass="#{loginBean.loggeduser.picStyle}"/>
```

and i'd like to define in my backing bean:

```
public String picStyle() {
  if (userA) {
   //get userA's image
     return "yourcss";
  } else {
     return "default";
  }
}
```

i'm not sure this is the best way but i guess it should work even with `style` attribute

Comment: OP doesn't want/need to load image from a CSS style. Instead, he wants/needs to get the image, basing on some property of the bean, like username.

Comment: that's what i'm trying to do.